# Getting error: CodeIgniter\Database\BaseResult::getResult in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to use CodeIgniter 4 crud function findAll and I am getting the error Argument 1 passed to CodeIgniter\Database\BaseResult::getResult()  as shown below:

[image]

Here is my model

```html
<?php 
namespace App\Models\Admin\User_management;
use CodeIgniter\Model;

class UsuariosModel extends Model
{
    
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
    
    protected $returnType = 'array';

    protected $allowedFields = ['user_login', 'user_psw', 'user_full_name', 'user_email', 'user_telef', 'user_image', 'user_date_of_birth', 'user_gender', "user_created_at", "user_updated_at", "user_deleted_at"];

    protected $useTimestamps = true;
    protected $useSoftDeletes = true;

    protected $createdField  = 'user_created_at';
    protected $updatedField  = 'user_updated_at';
    protected $deletedField  = 'user_deleted_at';
```

and this is my controller

```html
 public function delete_users(){
        //$this->validateViewUserData();
        //$user_id = $this->request->getVar('user_id', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        //$this->deleteUsers($user_id);
        
        
        $user_model = new UsuariosModel();
        
        $users = $user_model->findAll();
    }
```

```html
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_login` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `user_psw` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `user_full_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `user_email` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `user_telef` int(16) NOT NULL,
  `user_image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `user_updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_deleted_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_date_of_birth` date NOT NULL,
  `user_gender` int(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=119 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Other crude functions like update, save, delete are working well, only when i use find() or findAll() dont work in controller and in model itself

Comment: Looks like you are using an older version of CI 4.0.2 maybe? Have you tried to use the lastest version?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw i was using the 4.0.2 but now i am using 4.0.4 and the problem still the same, so i dont know whats going on

Comment: Well I have taken your code, created a test schema based upon your settings, and I Cannot Re-create your Error using CI 4.04 on PHP 7.4.8 - (Kubuntu 18.04). Can you supply a sample Database Schema.

Comment: Just double check your line numbers for the error have changed just to make sure you do have the new system installed... grasping at straws here but worth the check.

Comment: Nope, still no error. I get back a result from my dummy insert. Performing a getLastQuery() to inspect the SQL, I get - SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`user_deleted_at` IS NULL.  So not sure what is different at your end. Have you tried reinstalling the system folder from fresh, even though you did the upgrade to CI 4.04. I just cannot break it.

Comment: All I can think of is Are you sure that is the code that's breaking and not somewhere else?

Comment: i installed a fresh CI connect to db and i am getting the same error

Comment: The only constant here is the data in the table. Can you provide any of your inserted data? I can only replicate your error if I physically force it by setting $this-returnType = NULL; inside the system/Model.php Line 355 - CI 4.0.4. It's Also works under CI 4.0.2. I cannot see how your code is doing this. Do any of your other similar models work on other tables? We are missing something here.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw   1
-maurodias
123
Alex  Dias
mauro@gmail.com
923525252
user2-160x160.jpg
2020-05-26 14:42:28
2020-07-21 10:36:31
NULL
1990-04-04
1

Comment: One thing to note, you have user_telef as an int(11) to store telephone numbers? Should that not be a varchar(16)? One other thing, can you run the command "select * FROM users" from something like phpmyadmin or using straight ole fashioned SQL from CI.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218292/discussion-between-timbrownlaw-and-mauro-dias).

Comment: One thing I've not asked ... which DBDriver are you using?

Answer (score 3):

i've had the same problem.
To solve it, you need to call the
base class constructor in the model constructor tha you're using:
parent:__construct();

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, i found the issue, in my model i was using the constructor,
`public function __construct(){ $this->DB = \Config\Database::connect(); $this->BUILDER = $this->DB->table($this->table);  }`
i remove that now find and findAll are working

Comment: You can add "parent::__construct();" at the begining of your constructor, then carry on with your constructor codes.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably due to the constructor that you have issue in your model files or your controller files. Just check that. Use the code below. Do not use any constructor in the Model files.

Model View

```
class UsuariosModel extends Model
{
    
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
    
    protected $returnType = 'array';

    protected $allowedFields = ['user_login', 'user_psw', 'user_full_name', 'user_email', 'user_telef', 'user_image', 'user_date_of_birth', 'user_gender', "user_created_at", "user_updated_at", "user_deleted_at"];

    protected $useTimestamps = true;
    protected $useSoftDeletes = true;

    protected $createdField  = 'user_created_at';
    protected $updatedField  = 'user_updated_at';
    protected $deletedField  = 'user_deleted_at';
}
```

In Controller

```
use App\Models\UsuariosModel;

$myObject = new UsuariosModel()
$query  = $myObject->findAll();

echo '<pre>';
print_r($query);
exit;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error using CI 4.1.9 when I had added a constructor to the CI Model. To resolve it (as pointed out by @emmmm and @heli-sangueve) I used the following

```
public function __construct() 
{
    parent::__construct();

    //other constructor code here
}
```

I hope this helps someone else. I would have added comments to the above answers, but didn't have the reputation...

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter 4 has predefined variables on the model but few of them only need `true` or `fals`, you just need to careful with them:

These are the following defined variables with `protected` scope in `model`:

```
protected $table = '';
protected $primaryKey = 'id';
protected $useAutoIncrement = true;
protected $returnType = 'array';
protected $useSoftDeletes = true;
protected $allowedFields = [];
protected $useTimestamps = false;
protected $createdField = 'created_at';
protected $updatedField = 'updated_at';
protected $deletedField = 'deleted_at';
protected $validationRules = [];
protected $validationMessages = [];
protected $skipValidation = false;
```

Try this one:

```
change $useSoftDeletes value from `true` to `false`
```

and run if it fixes your problem then no need to do anything else.
In case this can not helps to fix the problem then comment these all variables and only uncomment `$table` and `$allowedFields` then refresh the page if it fixes the problem then one by one check the rest `boolean` cases with `true` or `false` might be the real problem really on one of them.
In my case, I had this problem.

`Note:`
Also rember one ,thing in case if you use constructer method on `controller` or `model` then must call `parent::__construct();` otherwise, it will through this error:

```
>     TypeError
>     CodeIgniter\Database\BaseResult::getResult(): Argument #1 ($type) must be of type string, null given, called in
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php 
namespace App\Models\Admin\User_management;
use CodeIgniter\Model;

class UsuariosModel extends Model
{
    
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
    
    protected $returnType = 'array';

    protected $allowedFields = ['user_login', 'user_psw', 'user_full_name', 'user_email', 'user_telef', 'user_image', 'user_date_of_birth', 'user_gender', "user_created_at", "user_updated_at", "user_deleted_at"];

    protected $useTimestamps = true;
    protected $useSoftDeletes = true;

    protected $createdField  = 'user_created_at';
    protected $updatedField  = 'user_updated_at';
    protected $deletedField  = 'user_deleted_at';
    
    
 public function __construct(){
 parent::__construct();
 $db = \Config\Database::connect();
 $this->builder = $db->table('NAME OF THE TABLE');
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with more information on how this resolved the question.

Answer (score -1):

You should probably check where this getResult() is called. The only way to have this error is to pass explicitiy something null to getResult() method.

Probably a variable not declared properly somewhere.

Comment: is been called by this  $users = $user_model->findAll(); in my controller the code for function delete_users()